# C parsing packets from pcap file

Tags: c, wireshark-dissector

I'm new to networking and trying to write pcap files comparison tool as a way to learn network programming
this is a snippet of my code (I writing `dll` to be used later in `c#`)

```
ptt_packet PcapDPI(ptt_ethernetheader puc_PacketData , size_t size)
{
    uint8_t *head = (uint8_t*)puc_PacketData;
    ptt_ethernetheader ether_header;
    ptt_ipheader ip_header;
    ptcp_header_t tcp_header;
    pudp_header_t udp_header;

    ether_header = (ptt_ethernetheader)head;
    head += sizeof(*ether_header);

    if (0x0800 == ntohs(ether_header->type))/*IP*/
    {

        ip_header = (ptt_ipheader)head;
        head += sizeof(*ip_header);


        /* now we need to check if tcp or udp*/
        if (ntohs(0x06) == ipProtocolNtohsRes)/*TCP*/
        {
            //tcp_header = (ptcp_header_t)((uint8_t*)puc_PacketData + 20);

            tcp_header = (ptcp_header_t)head;
            head += sizeof(*tcp_header);            

        }
        else if (ntohs(0x11) == ipProtocolNtohsRes)/*UDP*/
        {
            udp_header = (pudp_header_t)head;
            head += sizeof(*udp_header);
        }
 }
```

As you can see I've started parsing the headers one after the other 
(`eth->ip->tcp/udp`)

**My question is:** is there is a way to maybe use `wireshark dissectors` outside of `wireshark`
or even better: does anyone knows about an `open source lib` that do all the dirty job of populating packet struct